# A different CSRF token and session ID passed in the request

Tags: csrf, session-management

A CSRF token is what a server includes in its response, that is the same token which is passed in the request from the user.

In my case, a different CSRF token is getting included in the request- which is hence generating a 403 Forbidden error.

Along the different CSRF token cookie, a new session ID cookie is also getting included, which should not be the case. I am guessing a new session is somehow getting created and hence including a different CSRF token but I am really not sure how and why is this happening. Seems a sort of re-login is happening.

What is more interesting is that this is happening only for a specific user. Any ideas what might be the case?

Comment: Sounds like the user is accessing the site with multiple tabs open.

Comment: Do you have any other information regarding traffic which is coming from that user?  Standard W3C logs should hopefully have that information.

Comment: @user52472, do you mean server logs? In my django.logs- I have the same - "CSRF token missing or incorrect" error.

Comment: @JohnWu, seems to be happening in a single tab.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely scenario with the information you've given us is that the user has opened a session in one window.  They they open a new browser window, where there initial session times out and they are given a new session identifier.  Now, they go back to their original browser window, and try and submit that form.  This is where your expired information is coming from.

Comment: Hi @user52472, this is not the scenerio unfortunately. I tested it on my machine with the user's credentials and got the same error. The thing you described seems to be happening in the same session and I am not sure how